# safari mutes audio from autoplayed videos

Tags: javascript, browser, safari, policy, autoplay

Knowing that many browsers has changed their policies about autoplayed medias, is there a way to bypass it, or, in the case of safari, reactivate the audio that has been muted when the next video is starting ?

In the safari case, the next video is starting but the audio is muted, i try to re-enable the volume to 1 via javascript but i can't until the user do it himself.

In firefox case, the next video doesn't start, `document.querySelector('video').play();` is blocked by the browser.